# Sort a list of lists by increasing order of elements

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

What is the quickest way to sort a list of lists of integers, such that the first sorting criterion is the first element of the list, the next is the second element of the list and so on?

E.g. The list

`list = {{1,3,4,5}, {1,2,4,3}, {1,1,2,8}, {1,3,5,6}, {1,2,3,4}}`

would under these rules be sorted to

`sortedlist = {{1,1,2,8}, {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,4,3}, {1,3,4,5}, {1,3,5,6}}`

Comment: Simply  `Sort[list]` , No ?

Comment: Yes, you're right - I was trying to do something more complicated than this simple example which was a list of lists of lists, but I could use this to do `Table[Sort[list[[i]] , {i, 1, Length[list]}]`. Thanks

Comment: @nonreligious - Rather than use `Table`, map the `Sort` onto the `list`, i.e., `Sort /@ list`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the sublists have equal lengths,

```
list[[Ordering[list]]]
```

> {{1, 1, 2, 8}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 5, 6}}

With possibly unequal lengths:

```
list[[Ordering[PadRight @ list]]]
```

> {{1, 1, 2, 8}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 5, 6}}

Comment: I see, I had thought I would need to use `SortBy[list, {#[[1]] &, #[[2]] &, #[[3]] &}]` but this works.

Comment: If the lengths are unequal the later parts that are being explicitly referenced may not exist. This would result in a `Part::partw` error message.

Comment: @BobHanlon, right. `Ordering` with `PadRight` works without that issue.

Answer (score 4):

With equal lengths, the simplest answer, as andre314 says in the comment above, is simply [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort):

```
Sort[list]
```

> {{1, 1, 2, 8}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 5, 6}}

With unequal lengths, kglr's [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering) + [`PadRight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight) approach is probably optimal.